# Azure Kinect: how to find the windows device id

Tags: azurekinect

I have been developing a Win application that uses 3 Azure Kinects. Since there is no C# wrapper available yet, I made a C++ app that does what I need and the C# app just grabs its output files.
I now need to figure out which camera is which. In the C# app I can get the windows device id in a form similar to

```
\\.\USB#VID_045E&PID_097C#001007692912#{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}
```

However the C API for the Kinect only provides ways to get the serial number of the device.
I tried to dig into the API, since I'm sure it must be somewhere in the code but, due to my limited C skills, I got lost pretty quickly.

Anybody with the same issue or can help?
Thanks,
Guido

Answer (score 1):

The SDK is designed to use serial number specifically to determine which device or devices you are connected to. If you are just trying to use 2 Kinects with 2 instances of your C# then you will need to open devices until you find the serial number you are looking for. If you are trying to use multiple devices in a master/subordinate configuration then you can query for jack state to determine if you have connected to one or the other.

Also please be aware that we just released our own C# wrapper for the SDK. Checkout https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/608 and https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/namespace_microsoft_1_1_azure_1_1_kinect_1_1_sensor.html for more details.